# jQuery dialog resize before opening

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm a bit stuck while trying to get a jQuery UI dialog window to automatically resize to fit it's contents, while maintaining a maximum height (so the dialog doesn't grow "out" of the window). The following code does work, however the dialog stays open on the top of the window, rather then centered (where I want it to appear).

```
jQuery(".dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    autoResize: true,
    height: "auto",
    hide: "fold",
    maxHeight: 500,
    open: function(event, ui) { jQuery(this).css({"max-height": 500, "overflow-y": "auto"}); },
    resizable: false,
    show: "fadeIn",
    width: 500
});
```

The open function does the trick, however it does this after opening the dialog (you can actually see it resize on the fly). Can anybody think of a trick to have it re-center itself within the window element? I tried using .position(), to no avail:

```
open: function(event, ui) {
    jQuery(this).css({"max-height": 500, "overflow-y": "auto"});
    setTimeout("jQuery(this).position(my: \"center\", at: \"center\", of: window)", 1000);
},
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The best trick I've come up with is to precalculate the size of the contents myself before creating the dialog (by adding them to a DOM element whose css class places them at a negative position in relation to the screen), and changing what value I pass in for the `height` based on whether that size is bigger than or smaller than the maximum size I'm going for.

PS: I don't know exactly how `position` works, but you might want to try:

```
setTimeout("jQuery(this).position({my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window})", 1000);
```

Comment: Important to note that placing an element at negative coordinates will briefly show scrollbars on the screen, or alter the appearance of them if they are already shown. I'd suggest using the css: `position: absolute; visibility: hidden; display: block;` and then call `height()` and/or `width()`

Comment: @BryanRoss: Interesting. I haven't noticed that effect. I'll look into it.